# How to delete a registry value using a registry file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, autostart

### 1. How to delete a registry value using a registry file?

I have learned that I can add a registry value to Windows registry with this command in a batch file.

```
regedit "path\Reg File Name.reg"
```

The registry file contains:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"Title"="Path"
```

This is working.

But nothing happens when I want to delete the registry value `Title` with a registry file containing following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"Title"="Path" =-
```

`=-` does nothing. How to fix this? What I'm doing wrong?

---

### 2. How to run the batch file hidden in background without a visible console window after user log on?

I have done this:

I created a batch file with:

```
wscript.exe "path\Script.vbs" "path\My File.bat"
```

And the VB script file contains:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

This is working. I'm clicking my `start.bat` and it starts `My File.bat` invisible in background.

But it is not working on adding the file `Start.bat` to `Autostart` folder in Windows start menu. When the system boots and I log in, batch file is really run and also the VB script, but `My File.bat` is not executed.

I mean everything is working beside my batch file which should run in background.

Answer (score 3):

The registry file must be as follows for deletion of a registry value.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"Title"=-
```

This registry file just deletes the value with name `Title` under registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

**Regedit** has an option to run silently: `/s`

So the following command line imports the content of the registry file into Windows registry without showing a message for the user, except the used user account does not have administrator privileges required on usage of **regedit**.

```
%SystemRoot%\regedit.exe /s "path\Reg File Name.reg"
```

If the registry file contains just data to remove a key or a value, nothing is imported and just the keys/values are removed silently.

A better solution for deleting just a single value than using **regedit** with a registry file is the usage of command **reg**.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\reg.exe delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "Title" /f
```

Run the command `reg /?` in a command prompt window to get help on command **reg** and `reg delete /?` for help on how to delete a registry value or key.

The advantage of using command **reg** in comparison to **regedit** is that the command does not require administrator privileges on modifying something under **HKCU** while the usage of **regedit** requires administrator privileges even for modifications in current user registry.